# When populating a slice with length set at runtime, do I absolutely need two loops, one for determining the length and one for populating?

Tags: arrays, loops, go, slice

So I have a function that removes punctuation from a string and puts those punctuation characters and their index into two slices:

```
func removeAndIndexPunctuation(word string) (string, []rune, []int) {
    // Index punctuation
    numberOfPunct := 0
    for _, char := range word {
        if unicode.IsPunct(char) {
            numberOfPunct += 1
        }
    }

    punctuations := make([]rune, numberOfPunct)
    punctuationIndex := make([]int, numberOfPunct)

    x := 0
    for i, char := range word {
        if unicode.IsPunct(char) {
            punctuations[x] = char
            punctuationIndex[x] = i
            x += 1
        }
    }

    // Remove all punctuation from word string
    res := r.ReplaceAllString(word, "")
    return res, punctuations, punctuationIndex
}
```

In order to make and populate the slices I have to run two for loops, one for counting the number of punctuations so I can make the array the correct length and then another that's pretty much the same except now I populate the slices.

In Python though I don't need two for loops since Python supports "dynamic arrays":

```
def removeAndIndexPunctuation(word):
    punctuations = []
    # Index punctuation
    for i, char in enumerate(word):
        if char in string.punctuation:
            punctuations.append((char, i))
    # Remove all punctuation from word string
    word = word.encode("utf-8").translate(None, string.punctuation).decode("utf-8")
    return word, punctuations
```

So I just want to make sure, in this case in golang, do I absolutely need two for loops because it doesn't support dynamic arrays or am I missing something? Or in other words, If I'm looping over a set of characters and adding some to an array/slice, do I really need two loops, one for counting the number of characters for setting the length of the slice, and one for populating the slice?

I come from Python and am learning Go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. Golang slices are dynamic arrays (don't confuse them for the actual arrays). You should (re-)read the excellent [golang slice internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) blog post about it.

Here is your example rewritten in a more idiomatic way:

```
func removeAndIndexPunctuation(word string) (string, []rune, []int) {
    var punctuations []rune
    var indexes []int

    for i, char := range word {
        if unicode.IsPunct(char) {
            punctuations = append(punctuations, char)
            indexes = append(indexes, i)
        }
    }

    // Remove all punctuation from word string
    res := r.ReplaceAllString(word, "")
    return res, punctuations, indexes
}
```

Note that I don't think the use of `regex` is particularly relevant here. Here is another version using a slice of runes:

```
func removeAndIndexPunctuation(word string) (string, []rune, []int) {
    var punctuations []rune
    var indexes []int
    var result []rune

    for i, char := range word {
        if unicode.IsPunct(char) {
            punctuations = append(punctuations, char)
            indexes = append(indexes, i)
        } else {
            result = append(result, char)
        }
    }

    return string(result), punctuations, indexes
}
```